# Delete MySQL data on a specific date, that is given in the data

Tags: php, sql

I have a data entry with 4 values ( id, subject, name, deliverydate).
now I need a PHP script that removes this entry when the deliverydate is reached, example:

(id:.. subject... name:... deliverdate:04.06.2021)
this entry needs to be deleted on the 4th of june 2021.

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Write a script that does `DELETE FROM table WHERE deliverydate >= NOW()` and run it as cron job

Comment: Why would you want to delete them in the first place?

Comment: so that they stop showing up in my html table

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a job to delete the rows, running it -- say -- once per day.

However, I would recommend that you use a view instead of or along with a job:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*
    from t
    where delivery_date < curdate();
```

Users of the view will never see data that is already deleted.  This will work, even if a job does not run or gets delayed for some reason.  I'm not a fan of hard-deleting data, but you can still delete data periodically at convenient times -- for instance, on the weekend when the database might have a lower load.

Comment: so i basically create a php file with your code in it and let it run as a cron job on a daily basis? thats it?

Comment: @MikkaKummer . . . No.  You create a view in the database once and then access the table through the view.  Periodically, you can run a query that actually deletes the rows.

Comment: OK @GordonLinoff, so I managed to create a view with your SQL code, but somehow it doesn't show any entrys. I'm quite confused, shouldn't the entrys with an later on date be shown here?

Comment: @MikkaKummer . . . I fixed the `where` clause.